What's the state-of-the-art in generic unification?
The Wikipedia page on unification mentions several generalizations of the basic Robinson unification problem. These seem to boil down to

Making the terms in the domain of discourse more interesting (higher-order unification, sorts, infinite terms, graph rewriting),
Making equivalence between terms more interesting ($E$-unification).

Both of these problems (arbitrarily interesting terms, arbitrarily interesting equivalence) are undecidable in general. In both cases, there is a substantive literature on well-behaved fragments of the problem and on semi-algorithms for undecidable fragments. Additionally, there is work that merges these fragments together with systems that can handle both extensions, often with various tradeoffs.
What's the "best" people have currently done?
I'm interested to know this as a function of definitions of "best"—what algorithm can handle the biggest set of higher-order unifications? What algorithm can handle the biggest set of $E$-unifications? What algorithm can handle the biggest set of higher-order $E$-unifications? What's the picture for semi-algorithms? Is there a systematic way to combine these sorts of algorithms, or to interpret one problem as an instance of the other? Is generality at the cost of (asymptotic/real-world) performance?
I've had trouble parsing the literature on this topic, as people writing with different applications in mind (abstract term rewriting, theorem proving, proof assistants, functional logic programming, metatheory) seem to use different language, or at least to not clearly relate their use of terms to the general schema outlined on Wikipedia. (E.g. I can't quite grok what it is that Curry's needed narrowing algorithm optimally solves.) Additionally, most of the literature I can find is 20 years old. I'm sure there have been advances and points of view not captured by it.
Help appreciated.

I like this question as a "literature survey", though I am skeptical about the "best" wording: Is unification modulo AC "better" than 3rd order unification of $\lambda$-terms?
